# Can't deploy website through Vercel or Netilify. Does anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, vercel

Good day guys.

I just finished a project that uses tailwindcss, parcel, and javascript in it. While I was in development mode with my localhost it was running perfectly fine and had no issue with loading and working on it. But when I tried to use Vercel to deploy it that is when the error occurred as you can see below. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem I would highly appreciate any feedback.

This is the error message Vercel gives me.

**Error message**

[image]

Comment: "Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?" seems noteworthy.

Comment: Did you override the [install command](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/build-step#install-command)?

Comment: Can you share the full log as text?

Comment: Hi sorry I'm new to web development what do you mean the full log text? I don't know if this helps but in package.json I have only dependencies of parcel-bundler and tailwindcss and I didn't install them as devDependacies. Is this wrong should they be devDependacies and not just dependacies ?

Comment: Basically the output above suggests the build isn't running `npm install` for some reason. So I'm asking for you to try to get more information from the log than the screenshot you posted. More information about your configuration (see my 2nd comment) would be useful as well.